# webpack with Babel not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I run in the Windows command prompt : npm start

and get:

> JavaScript-ES6@1.0.0 start C:\Dans\Courses\JavaScript-ES6
>   webpack-dev-server

× ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! JavaScript-ES6@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the JavaScript-ES6@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the JavaScript-ES6 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs JavaScript-ES6
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls JavaScript-ES6
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

---

My webpack.config.js file content:

const path = require('path');

```
   module.exports = {
   entry: ['./app/index.js'],
   output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
       filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
       loaders: [
         {  
           loader: 'babel-loader',
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/
         }
        ]
   },
     devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: './build',
        inline: true
    }
}
```

---

My package.json file content:

```
{
  "name": "JavaScript-ES6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "build": "webpack",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server"
 },
   "babel": {
   "presets": ["es2015"]
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webpack config has one error in it.
Inside module, the keyword needs to be **rules** instead of **loaders**.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   entry: ['./app/index.js'],
   output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
       filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
       rules: [ //here
         {  
           loader: 'babel-loader',
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/
         }
        ]
   },
     devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: './build',
        inline: true
    }
}
```